# Nested quotations issue - $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] not working

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<form method='post' style='display:inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='<?php echo $_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\'];?>'> <input type='submit' name='delete' class='button' value='Delete'></form>";
```

For some reason, no matter what combination I try with nested quotations, I just can't get the above to work correctly.

Any ideas? Really, it would be much appreciated. I've looked everywhere.

Comment: Please read [ask], explain what you expect to happen and show what actually happens. With "not working" we can't do anything.

Comment: Because you use the <?php like it was a text... use `print "some text " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; . "";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "<form method='post' style='display:inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'> <input type='submit' name='delete' class='button' value='Delete'></form>";
```

You are trying to open php tags again inside a php echo

Answer (score 0):

Double echo in your code so try it..note: close php code before using this.

```
<form method='post' style='display:inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>'> <input type='submit' name='delete' class='button' value='Delete'></form>";
```